# Define hyperplane out of 4 points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given the Cartesian co-ordinates (x,y,z,w) of 4 non-coplanar points:
$P1:(x1,y1,z1,w1)$
$P2:(x2,y2,z2,w2)$
$P3:(x3,y3,z3,w3)$
$P4:(x4,y4,z4,w4)$
 I want to find the equation of the hyperplane on which they lie on. I assume the equation will be of the form: $A1x+A2y+A3z+A4w=A$
How do I find $A1, A2, A3, A4, A$ in relation to the above co-ordinates?

Comment: if they're non-coplanar vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^4$ then $A = \mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: @Emisor I think that "coplanar" is not to be interpreted this way, but with the meaning "do not belong to a same 2D plane".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct way (and easy for calculations aided by computer) is by writing that the following determinant is zero:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x\\
y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4&y\\
z_1&z_2&z_3&z_4&z\\
w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4&w\\
1&1&1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

The proof is easy: when expanded along its last column, this determinant can be expressed like this:

$$x\begin{vmatrix}
y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4\\
z_1&z_2&z_3&z_4\\
w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4\\
1&1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}-y\begin{vmatrix}
x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\\
z_1&z_2&z_3&z_4\\
w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4\\
1&1&1&1
\end{vmatrix}+\cdots=0$$

which has

- the desired first-degree form $ax+by+cz+dw+e=0$,
- and is such that, if you replace $(x,y,z,w)$ by one of the $(x_k,y_k,z_k,w_k)$, $k=1,2,3,4$, it is 0, due to the classical property of a determinant that, if two column (the k-th and the fifth) are identical, the determinant is $0$.

For a different explanation, see for example [this reference, explaining it in 3D](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)) (equ. (18)).

Comment: Thank you! your explanation is very helpful .